# Powr Form CSS Customisation (Button & Captcha alignment)

Tags: css

I have a form at the bottom of the following website:

https://www.smartbuild.uk.com/

I would like to get the Submit button and the Captcha box to sit on the same 'line'  (bottom level aligned).

The form was built using Powr, and has a CSS code box to make customisation.

I've read Powr's [CSS help](https://help.powr.io/hc/en-us/articles/115005476587-Using-custom-CSS-and-Javascript-in-POWr-Plugins) but can't get a solution - I don't even know what object references to use.

I'm guessing something like:

.CaptureFrame {width: 75% !important;}
.Submitbutton {width: 25% !important;}
+ something else to get them on same line?

I had a go at inspecting the page html to find objects but I know nothing about html or CSS!

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all, _“but I know nothing about html or CSS”_ is not a good basis to come asking here on this site … you are supposed to bring a knowledge of some basics, it is not the job of this site to replace beginner’s tutorials.

Comment: Secondly, what you want is probably not a good idea to begin with - at least not with the given HTML structure. The div element that comes after the captcha and contains the submit button, contains half a dozen other divs before the submit button - to hold different kinds of error messages, in case they occur (such as the message “Please fill in required fields.” when you try to submit the form without filling in anything.) Now even if you floated that container next to the captcha, these kinds of error messages will likely not fit next to it, so the whole block will go down again then …

Comment: I guess your best bet in that current scenario would be to position the button absolute. The buttonContainer element it is in is positioned relative already, so it can serve as an anchor point. `#submitButton { position: absolute; right: 0; top: -75px; }` - positioning this from the top and not the bottom is important here, because the height of the container changes, when error messages appear. (Make sure this doesn’t affect any other elements with the same id, should any occur in other places of the site. Might need a different selector in that case.)

Comment: The site doesn’t seem to be optimized for mobile displays in any way, but just zooms the desktop view, so chances that this absolutely positioned button will misbehave under different screen resolutions are rather slim, I think. Make sure to properly test different cases nevertheless.

Comment: @04Fs - I accept your first comment - I did think twice about posting such a blatant 'please do this for me' request!  I'm very grateful for your input.